# Bug with Thread.pause

Tags: java, swing, timer, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

This is my code:

```
private void jButton5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    this.jButton5.setText("VietNam");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    this.jButton5.setText("Ha Noi");
}
```

I want the Button display "Viet Nam", and after one minute it'll change to "Ha Noi".
But with my code, my Button displayed nothing and after 1 minute it displayed "Ha Noi", without "Viet Nam" appeared for a single second.

How can I fix that? I don't want to use swing.Timer because it can't pause the system completely. If there is a way to fix it, please tell me.

Thanks you guys a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have executed `Thread.sleep()` on the GUI thread, which prevented it from making any further updates of the GUI.

The most convenient way to schedule a future action in the GUI is by using `javax.swing.Timer`, which see in the Javadocs.

Comment: I see. Can I do anything to stop other buttons from working while Timer is running?

Comment: I guess you should disable them by calling the appropriate method.